# VB 2013 WPF: How do I add text to a textbox programmatically as if it were typed with a keyboard?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, keyboard, visual-studio-2013

I have a user interface for on touchscreens for human-machine interfaces for industrial machinery. It's programmed in VB.net 2013 (just switched from 2010) express using WPF.

I am trying to make some buttons that are emulating a keypad type text into a TextBox the same way a keyboard would (using the Windows 7 on-screen keyboard is not an option, it is too ugly and the buttons are too small, yadda yadda). How do I make a Button's click event handler send a message into the program such that it is handled exactly the same way as if I had a keyboard and pressed a number key on the keyboard? I don't want to have to re-invent the wheel for stuff like selecting text, inserting numbers into the middle of an existing string, and so on. The existing "solution" for this "EditKeypad" class simply concatenates the new number on to the end of the existing string, which is lame.

I have tried an event handler like so (just sending the '4' key for now):

```
                ValueInputBox.Focus()

            'create a pretend "key press" to emulate a real keyboard by raising a key press event
            Dim myKeyEvent As KeyEventArgs = New KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 0, Key.D4)
            myKeyEvent.RoutedEvent = UIElement.KeyDownEvent
            InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(myKeyEvent)
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything, the program just pauses for a second and nothing appears in my TextBox. This is in spite of being able to type in the same TextBox with an actual USB keyboard.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you want to use SendKeys()? If not, you will have to use some Windows API's for sending windows messages.

Comment: SendKeys() is a WinForms thing, and since I'm in WPF land, I have no SendKeys. The code above is the closest thing I could find to SendKeys, but like I said... no dice so far.

Comment: `The existing "solution" for this "EditKeypad" class simply concatenates the new number on to the end of the existing string, which is lame.` What is lame about it? Does that not accomplish what you want? Can't you just raise a keypress event after appending the text?

Comment: If I have a 9 digit number and select three digits in the middle of it: 123456789, select the 456 with the mouse then press the 0 on the keyboard, I get 1230789. If I select 456 again with the mouse and press my 0 key on my EditKeypad, I get 1234567890 and the 456 becomes deselected. Inconsistent behaviour and undesired results. I just want to use the built-in functionality of text selection and replacement that is in Windows/.NET/etc rather than reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: Sorry, had no idea Sendkeys was a winforms only thing.  What's wrong with the windows messaging API? I would guess this is exactly what the standard touch keyboard does.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but you'll have to live with a C# implementation:

```
var key = Key.A;
var target = Keyboard.FocusedElement as TextBox;

target.RaiseEvent(new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, PresentationSource.FromVisual(target), 0, key) { RoutedEvent = Keyboard.PreviewKeyDownEvent });
target.RaiseEvent(new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, PresentationSource.FromVisual(target), 0, key) { RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent });
target.RaiseEvent(new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, PresentationSource.FromVisual(target), 0, key) { RoutedEvent = Keyboard.PreviewKeyUpEvent });
target.RaiseEvent(new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, PresentationSource.FromVisual(target), 0, key) { RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyUpEvent });

target.RaiseEvent(new TextCompositionEventArgs(InputManager.Current.PrimaryKeyboardDevice, new TextComposition(InputManager.Current, target, "A")) { RoutedEvent = TextCompositionManager.TextInputEvent });
```

The first four will trigger appropriate KeyDown/Up for some controls. However, the TextBox uses the TextInputEvent instead, and thus, the second Event type.

So the short version of your answer is that the TextBox does not respond to KeyDown, but TextComposition.